# Red Recording Bar in-app

Tags: objective-c, ios, statusbar

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [iOS: Pulsing red double-height status bar](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11319382/ios-pulsing-red-double-height-status-bar)

For reference to what I mean by red status/recording bar, please see the Voice Memos app - it shows up once the recording is started and replaces the status bar with a double thick red bar.

[image]

I've been able to get this bar to appear when the app enters the background by flagging the app's background state as being an Audio/VoIP app. The bar does not appear when the user is in the app however - this is what I'd really like to achieve. The Voice Memos app from Apple has this functionality, but I was unable to find any documentation on how to do the same. Does anyone know if this is doable, or would I have to use some sort of library/hack?

Comment: You could write your own - display it and hide the status bar

Comment: Writing ones own isn't really possible if you want to display battery, carrier, etc as normal.